# AWS - Password Protecting a Domain

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, authentication

I have a NodeJS-based CMS application running on an AWS EC2 instance and I am looking for an easy way to password protect this application with username and password authentication to restrict access. Is there an easy way to set password protection for a domain on AWS?
Thanks,

Comment: Are you looking towards implenting authentication to the application or network restriction?

Comment: @Ashan - I am open to both. I was in the process of creating a Node JS user login page however, I don't have the time to complete this. So, I am looking for a more straight forward/easier option. There will only ever be two people access this application - myself and the person who I am developing it on behalf of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this repo: https://github.com/http-auth/http-auth
I think you just want to check user= pass= and just that... in that case is just a few lines code

```
var auth = require('http-auth');
var basic = auth.basic({
    realm: "Simon Area."
}, (username, password, callback) => { 
    // Custom authentication
    // Use callback(error) if you want to throw async error.
    callback(username === "Tina" && password === "Bullock");
}
);
```

Comment: cool this works. How can I enable a UI web form instead of an alert box though?

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079031/login-form-for-http-basic-auth
but you will need to use auth on a subfolder, so it checks for user/pass in that subfolder. is not very nice code, but it should work

Answer (score 1):

For authentication [AWS Cognito userpools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html), [Azure B2C](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/active-directory-b2c/), [auth0](https://auth0.com) are couple of SaaS solutions you can consider. Apart from that you can use, [passportJS](http://passportjs.org) for Node which simplifies implementation and integration.

Comment: How does Cognito work? Can I simply bind it to my application?

Comment: No you need to go through their API and connect. If you only go with user pools its like you get a db to store user data with basic operations such as register users, login, change password and etc. You need to write the glue code connecting this to a UI.