# HTTP authentication University timetable

Tags: javascript, forms, basic-authentication

My first post here but I'm trying to create a form which lets a user login to a HTTP Basic Authentication site (My universities time table) the reason for doing so is that it cant remember logins on iOS.
Here is what i have so far

```
<script>
function submitAuthForm() {
    var login = document.getElementById('login').value;
    var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    location = location.href.replace('://', '://' + encodeURIComponent(login) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(pass) + '@apps.example.com/TimeTables');
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.reload(true);
    }, 5000);
}
</script>
<form method="get" onsubmit="submitAuthForm(); return false">
    <input type="text" id="login" />
    <input type="password" id="pass" />
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
</form>
```

The Problem I'm having so far is that when the form is submitted its also attaching the current URL of the site its hosted on to the end causing the timetable service to throw errors.
Hope someone can help me out or give me a nudge in the right direction if I'm going the complete wrong way about this :)

Comment: Why are you doing a string replacement? `location.href = 'https://' + encodeURIComponent(…`?

Comment: I'm not totally sure to be honest i was trying to use it from somthing i found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079031/login-form-for-http-basic-auth

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are replacing the `://` part only, so you end with a mix of the original href and the string concatenations.

Instead of replacing, you could create a new href string:

```
location = location.protocol + '//' + encodeURIComponent(login) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(pass) + '@apps.example.com/TimeTables';
```

`location.protocol` returns a string like `http:` or `https:` and you concatenate the `//` and the login parts.

Comment: Ah thanks I've changed that part which seems to be displaying only the part i want however im now struggling to get the username and password to display in front of the URL when its outputted I'm looking to get something like this 'https://user:password@apps.example.com/TimeTables' but am just getting 'apps.uclan.ac.uk/DailyTimetable/' leading to a 404. Is there something I'm missing as to why this doesn't now work?