# HTTP get request to local server

Tags: html, get, httprequest

I'm trying to send authentication data to a local server https://localhost:5004/logs
this url should return json data.
Actually i have this error:
You are trying to authenticate to the website "localhost" as user “%5Bobject%20Object%5D”.

```
<form method="get" onsubmit="javascript:document.location='https://' + $('login') + ':' + $('pass') + '@localhost:5004/logs';">
<input type="text" name="login" id="login" />
<input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
<input type="submit" value="ok"/>
</form>
```

Tried also with

```
function add(login,pass) {
var str = login+':'+pass;
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://localhost:5004/logs";
http.open("GET", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
    alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(str);
}
```

same 401 error

Answer (score -1):

The `onsubmit` even handler attribute accepts JavaScript Directly, you don't need to prefix `javascript:`

```
<form method="get" onsubmit="document.location='https://' + $('login') + ':' + $('pass') + '@localhost:5004/logs';">
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" />
    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" />
    <input type="submit" value="ok"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by `$('login')`? This isn't valid JavScript.

Comment: got from here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3079031/login-form-for-http-basic-auth

Comment: That person is using Perl, are you too?

Comment: I guess I need to close this question.

Comment: That person uses jQuery too. Your case is completely different. You obviously cannot use any code Just like that. It's like putting C++ code in C#

Comment: You must tell what languages/frameworks/libraries  you are using